# Bootstrap containers, rows and col usage

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I understand for the most part containers and cols.  My question is about rows. Below is 50 / 50 Split.

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6">
          50 / 50 Content
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
          50 / 50 Content
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

If I was again, going to split one of these columns in an area do I again add another row div as below?

```
 <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
           50 / 50 Content
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                 Sub 50 / 50 Content
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                 Sub 50 / 50 Content
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
           50 / 50 Content
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your code should work. What is the question? also i would change the indentation, but that doesn't change the functionality, just makes the code more readable.

Comment: yes, its documented [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting)

Comment: Question is, every time I am sub-dividing a column do I add another row div that holds those sub columns?  Whether its 50 / 50, 20 / 80, etc... and as long as my cols add up to 12.

Comment: What have you tried? What happens? What do you want to happen? Please provide a [mcve]. You are probably looking for Bootstrap "Well".

Comment: Dani I have tried everything and everything has happened!!!!!  Thanks @tmg that is what I was looking for "Nested".  So yes, every time you have nested cols.  They are within a row.  AwesomeSauce!

Comment: You don't need a new row every 12 units. It's called "column wrapping"
. Just be aware of [responsive resets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping).

Comment: @ZimSystem, what about my example above? What if I were to have two sets of col6 within a col6?  Wouldnt I need a new row for each of the 12?

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap a div which has row class, inside divs paddings, margins and float settings will change.

Use both in the same page and be carefull for thees things.